# Converting list of objects into list of dto, spring. Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: spring, stream, dto, mapper

I want to map a list of Race into list of RaceDto. When I try to map it, I get an error: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

**RaceRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface RaceRepository extends CrudRepository<Race, Long> {
    List<Race> findAll();
    // ...

}
```

**RaceDtoMapper.java**

```
@Service
public class RaceDtoMapper {
    RaceDto map(Race race){
        RaceDto dto = new RaceDto();
        dto.setId(race.getId());
        dto.setMaxPlayers(race.getMaxPlayers());
        dto.setDescription(race.getDescription());
        dto.setLocation(race.getLocation());
        dto.setDate(race.getDate());
        dto.setState(race.getState());
        dto.setRaceEventId(race.getRaceEvent().getId());
        return(dto);
    }
}
```

**RaceService.java**

```
@Service
public class RaceService {
    private final RaceRepository raceRepository;
    private final RaceDtoMapper raceDtoMapper;
    private final RacePersonDtoMapper racePersonDtoMapper;

    public RaceService(RaceRepository raceRepository, RaceDtoMapper raceDtoMapper, RacePersonDtoMapper racePersonDtoMapper) {
        this.raceRepository = raceRepository;
        this.raceDtoMapper = raceDtoMapper;
        this.racePersonDtoMapper = racePersonDtoMapper;
    }

    List<RaceDto> getRaces(){
        return raceRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(RaceDtoMapper::map) // HERE IS THE CODE CAUSING THE ERROR
                .toList();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the method `map` while there's no instance of it.

Either make the method static:

```
static RaceDto map(Race race){
```

Or create an instance:

```
List<RaceDto> getRaces(){
    RaceDtoMapper raceDtoMapper = new RaceDtoMapper();
    return raceRepository.findAll()
        .stream()
        .map(raceDtoMapper::map) // use instance
        .toList();
}
```